# How to disable an AngularJS multiselect?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multi-select

I have an AngularJS multiselect

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 nobottommargin" id="multiSelect">
   <div class="nobottommargin multiselect-btn">
     <multiselect class="selectStates" data-ng-model="selectedStates" options="options" id-prop="code" display-prop="state" show-search="true" search-limit="50" select-text="Location" data-ng-change="onChange('state')"  ng-disabled=true></multiselect>
     <!--<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg not-dark" value="" placeholder="Where">-->
   </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to disable it evn by applying css properties.
I am new to AngularJS so I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and it worked

```js
<multiselect disabled="true"></multiselect>
```

Comment: do you want to make all option element disable or one of them?

Comment: I want to make the multiselect it self unclickable.

Comment: can you try disabled="true"

Comment: and also you can visit this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/mGnpQynWKkRLBC0VEHBR?p=preview

Comment: In this plunkr are you disabling?

Comment: you can add  disabled="true" to tag in this plunker

Comment: Yes its wrkng but not happening with my case.

Comment: can you share all your code to make us understand situation. Do you use angular directive ?

Comment: or you can look at plunker and make it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Try this If this is what  you need, This will disables all the multiselects, i.e. user will not be able to click on them.

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 nobottommargin" id="multiSelect">
               <div class="nobottommargin multiselect-btn" style="pointer-events:none">
                 <multiselect class="selectStates" data-ng-model="selectedStates" options="options" id-prop="code" display-prop="state" show-search="true" search-limit="50" select-text="Location" data-ng-change="onChange('state')"  ng-disabled=true></multiselect>
                 <!--<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg not-dark" value="" placeholder="Where">-->
               </div>
            </div>
```